# LDP VPLS - Packet behavior within bridge-groups and bridge-domains

Tags: cisco, juniper, mpls, vpls, pseudowire

I have a pair of ASR9k's that I plan on migrating to Juniper MX960's.  Below is a piece of the configuration:

```
l2vpn
 bridge group VPLS_1
  bridge-domain 101
   interface TenGigE0/2/0/0.101
   !
   vfi 101
    neighbor 1.1.1.1 pw-id 101
    !
   !
   routed interface BVI101
  !
  bridge-domain 202
   interface TenGigE0/2/0/0.202
   !
   neighbor 3.3.3.3 pw-id 3003
    pw-class ro-7450c-1
   !
   neighbor 3.3.3.4 pw-id 3003
    pw-class ws-7450a-2
   !
   vfi 202
    neighbor 2.2.2.2 pw-id 202
    !
   !
   routed interface BVI202
  !
  bridge-domain 11
   interface TenGigE0/1/0/6.11
   !
   interface TenGigE0/2/0/0.11
   !
   vfi 11
    neighbor 11.11.11.11 pw-id 11
    !
   !
  !
```

Where I'm confused is the multiple instances of `bridge-domain` inside a single `bridge-group` (I do have multiple `bridge-groups` that aren't shown.)

What purpose does each `bridge-domain` serve **while inside** a single `bridge-group`?  Does this break the split horizon rule for VPLS?  Couldn't I just make multiple VPLS instances in JUNOS?

Please let me know if anyone needs clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My background is mostly from the Junos side, but I think you are correct in your assumptions - your configuration is best served by multiple VPLS instances - particularly since there are multiple `vfi` statements, each with distinct pseudowire neighbors.

As to the purpose of the `bridge group` statement on the ASR, after much trawling, I came across the following link:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/asr-9000-series-aggregation-services-routers/116500-problemsolution-product-00.html

```
The Bridge Group (BG) is a non-functional configuration hierarchy that ties several 
BDs together in part of the same functional group.  It functions just as the 
creation of multiple individual groups with their domains does, as opposed to one 
group with multiple domains.
```

I read that as it being 'decorative' ;)